# Static Variable/Methods in PHP using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, static-variables

I'm saving the ID of the conected user in a static variable at MainController, but I need to access this variable in others controllers. When I try to get the value from the variable, the result is always the initial value of the variable, even when I have already modified it.

```
class MainController extends AppController {
    //...
    public static $loggedClienteId;

    //functions

    public function loginCliente(){
        //code...
        self::$loggedClienteId = $cliente['Cliente']['id'];
        var_dump(MainController::$loggedClienteId); //returns the correct value.
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'clientes', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

So, in another controller...

include "MainController.php";

```
class ClientesController extends AppController {
     public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index() {
        var_dump(MainController::$loggedClienteId); //null, althought it already has a value...
        $this->set('clientes', $this->Cliente->find('all'));
    }
    //functions...
}
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$this->Auth->user('id')` to get the current logged in user's id.

The reason your code does not work is because once the request for the login action is completed, the script is over. Setting a variable does not persist across requests. You have to save variables in the session for that.

If it's not the logged in user's id you need, what you have to do is use the `SessionComponent` and use `$this->Session->write('key', 'value');` and to read it in another request/controller `$this->Session->read('key');`.

Comment: Alternatively, if it is not necessary to persist the changed value across pages, you can simply read and write via Configure class to store and retrieve values. No need to have static hacks.